# Finding 32-bit Libraries on 64-bit Linux

Tags: linux, 64-bit, packages

I just installed the 64-bit version of Slackware and am setting up some software I was previously running (in 32-bit) from their tarballs.

Currently I'm trying to build lib `torrent-0.12.7`, which claims that it needs `libsigc++-2.0`.  I have `libsigc++-2.2.9` compiled and installed, but it doesn't seem to be finding it.

I notice that `libsigc++` is installed in:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

And it's the only thing there.  I also notice that `printenv` shows:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

So I would assume then that this means that it's looking for 64-bit packages in `lib64` directories, not 32-bit packages in `lib` directories.

What is the *right* way to get it to find this package?  Do I need to re-compile `libsigc++` with some kind of flags to install it in the 64-bit directories?  If so, how?  Or do I need to do something else?  If all I need to do is add that path to the above environment variable, how do I do that?  (There is no `setenv` on this machine for some reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up discovering that I need to use `export` to set my environment variables.  So in my `.zshrc` I added:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig; export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Now `./configure` finds the correct library.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd call `pkg-config` with the host prefix:

```bsh
$ uname -m
x86_64

$ i686-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config sigc++-2.0 --libs
-lsigc-2.0
```